# Can Install EGit: Missing requirement: Git Team Provider Core

Tags: git, eclipse-plugin, windows-7-x64, egit, coldfusionbuilder

So I am using Coldfusion Builder with Ecplise. I am trying to get EGit installed in it so I can do Git stuff. The only thing I can ever get installed is EGit 0.11.1 from `http://download.ecplise.org/releases/helios/`. When I try to install the latest version from `http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates` version 2.3.1.xxx I always get the Missing requirement error:

```
Missing requirement: Git Team Provider Core 2.3.1.201302201838-r (org.eclipse.egit.core 2.3.1.201302201838-r) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.core.runtime [3.7.0,4.0.0)' but it could not be found
Cannot satisfy dependency: From: Eclipse EGit 2.3.1.201302201838-r (org.eclipse.egit.feature.group 2.3.1.201302201838-r)
To: org.eclipse.egit.core [2.3.1.201302201838-r]
```

I can't figure out how to install the Git Team Provider Core. I've read some stuff about setting system config etc, but nothing I do seems to help. I've tried installing all different things like the Mylyn, JGit, etc, but I am obviously missing something important.

I do have Git Installed in Windows if that matters, but still nothing. This has to be a simply config issue right? I mean, the version I have installed (0.11.1) IS working as intended. I can pull/branch/push, all that good stuff. But my buddy noticed I was missing some options under the `Team` menu and I assume it's because I can't get the latest version up and running.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You said you were trying to update via `http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios/`, so sounds like you're still running Eclipse 3.6 (Helios).

According to the [EGit FAQ](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/FAQ#What_versions_of_Eclipse_does_EGit_target.3F), the latest version of EGit that is supported on Helios is 2.1.0.201209190230-r. It also says:

> If possible we will not prevent usage in older releases but if we want
>   to take advantage of new functionality only available in one of the
>   latest two Eclipse releases but not in older releases we will update
>   dependencies which will in fact discontinue support for older
>   releases.

You might have bumped into one of those dependencies that break EGit on your version of Eclipse.

I recommend either:

- Install EGit 2.1, the last supported version for Helios. Under "Help->Install New Software", add this site: http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates-2.1/ . Install EGit from there.
- Upgrade to Eclipse 3.7 (Indigo) or 4.2 (Juno, the latest) and try again with EGit 2.3. Be warned that upgrading Eclipse might open you up to new problems.

Comment: I was just pulling from updates, not updates 2-1. Looks to be working. I only reverted to helios because I was just looking for anything. I am running Ecplise 3.5.1

Comment: I apologize if I came across as lazy. When it comes to DVCS stuff I start reading documentation, my eyes cross, and I feel no more ahead than if I hadn't read it.

Comment: No problem, Leeish. I didn't think you were lazy at all. You did your research on the problem first, and wrote a detailed question. Glad EGit is working for you.

Comment: Worked, just make sure you uncheck the "import support" if you are running eclipse 3.7, this feature is only supported for 3.6