# how to install egit in zend studio 9.0.2 offline

Tags: offline, egit, zend-studio

install environment:

```
windows 7 64 bit/XP 32bit
zend stutdio 9.0.2
org.eclipse.egit.repository-3.1.0.201310021548-r
```

I want to use git in zend studio 9.0.2 .but my PC can not connect to the internet.so i download egit 3.1.0 package.i try to install this package in "install new software",but failed with error:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
Software being installed: Eclipse Git Team Provider 3.1.0.201310021548-r (org.eclipse.egit.feature.group 3.1.0.201310021548-r)
Missing requirement: Git Team Provider UI 3.1.0.201310021548-r (org.eclipse.egit.ui 3.1.0.201310021548-r) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.team.core [3.6.100,4.0.0)' but it could not be found
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Eclipse Git Team Provider 3.1.0.201310021548-r (org.eclipse.egit.feature.group 3.1.0.201310021548-r)
To: org.eclipse.egit.ui [3.1.0.201310021548-r]
```

can anyone help me?

Comment: can anyone tell me what version of eclipse does zend studio 9.0.2 target?

Answer (score 0):

This answer might be applicable to you: [Can Install EGit: Missing requirement: Git Team Provider Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15439104/can-install-egit-missing-requirement-git-team-provider-core) In other words, it is an internal version conflict between parts of Eclipse.

Comment: The point I was trying to make, is that this question is already answered in MANY places around the web, and on Stackoverflow.